# How do I use a C++ unique_ptr in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, components, entity, unique-ptr

TLDR: I think I'm using unique_ptr wrongly, but I'm not sure how to do this otherwise.

I am trying to write a simple physics engine wrapped up in an entity component system. The physics world is essentially the main manager class for all objects that are affected by physics, that should contain all physics properties for entities in the world(ideally stored in a std::vector). In every update loop, after the engine solves constraints, it iterates through the vector of physics objects stored in the physics world and applies the forces, accelerations, impulses etc.
There is also a SceneManager that stores more general entities (eg. for rendering etc) and a SceneEntity which stores behaviour specific components.

I chose to use vector<unique_ptr> for storage because there should only be one instance of each entity (physics or scene) - the end user can handle the raw pointer and pass it to functions etc, but the lifetime of the entities themselves are handled by the SceneManager and PhysicsWorld.

The general structure is as follows:

```
class PhysicsWorld
{
  private:
  unique_ptr<PhysicsEntity> entities;
  public:
  void addEntity(PhysicsEntity * entity)
  {
    unique_ptr<PhysicsEntity> entity_ptr(entity);
    entities.push_back(std::move(entity_ptr));
  }
}

class PhysicsEntity
{
 private:
 unsigned int id;
 float gravity;
 public:
 Entity();
 ~Entity();
 void setGravity(float val);
}
    
PhysicsWorld world{};
PhysicsEntity * physent = new PhysicsEntity{};
physent->setGravity(3.0f);
world.addEntity(physent)

SceneManager scene{};
RigidbodyComponent * rbcomp = new Rigidbody{ent};
SceneEntity * sceneEnt = new SceneEntity{};
sceneEnt->addComponent(rbcomp);
scene->addEntity(sceneEnt);
```

My problem is that when I run this code, I get an error from xutility saying "attempting to reference a deleted function" - I believe it occurs somwhere around world.addEntity(). After much searching, I've concluded that this is due to my use of unique_ptr. Is this error occurring because unique_ptr is not the right tool for the job, or am I missing something - or is the error elsewhere?

Comment: What is the specific deleted function it tells you you're trying to reference? Actually, more to the point: Where, in this code, is there a `vector` at all? `entities` is a single `unique_ptr`, not a `vector<unique_ptr>`.

Comment: Unique pointers cannot be copied, that's the most likely cause.

Comment: This code wouldn't compile

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had not defined move constructors and move assignment operators for PhysicsWorld, so it was using the default ones, which in turn were calling the (deleted) copy constructors for the PhysicsEntity stored in the vector. The code compiled after I defined those.